# Storing References to Objects of Different Classes

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I currently have two classes that I create objects from. I need an array that will store references (pointers) to these objects. Of what type should the array be?

```
ArrayList<Class1> visableObjs = new ArrayList<Class1>();
```

Will of course only store pointers to objects that stem from Class1. If I had an object from Class2 could I store it's pointer in the same array?

Comment: You could have both classes implement an interface, or have both classes share a common parent. Then you could set the type of your list to that of the interface or common parent. Which ever makes the most sense for what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean that the objects you store are instances of those two classes, you should make those classes inherit from a (custom?) class or interface and use that class/interface as the type to store in your array.

Comment: Class1 implements myClass, Class2 implements myClass, ArrayList<myClass>

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions.

Comment: You *shouldn't* make your two classes inherit from a common super class (or interface) unless they really *are* - in a meaningful sense - instances of this supertype.  You certainly shouldn't do it *just so you can put them in the same collection*.  If you do, you are conflating type with the need to aggregate elements in a heterogeneous collection.

Answer (score 0):

We can do like this. Its not good practice at all if objects are from different classes.

```
ArrayList<Object> visableObjs = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

or

```
ArrayList visableObjs = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use generics to create a Choice class to hold a reference to *one or other* type, but not both:

```
public final class Choice<A,B> {

    private final A a;
    private final B b;
    private final boolean isA;

    private Choice(A a, B b, boolean isA) {
        this.a = a; this.b = b; this.isA = isA;
    }

    public static <A,B> Choice<A,B> ofA(A a) {
        return new Choice<>(a, null, true);
    }
    public static <A,B> Choice<A,B> ofB(B b) {
        return new Choice<>(null, b, false);
    }

    public boolean isA() { return isA; }
    public A getA() {
       if(!isA) throw new IllegalStateException("Not a!");
       return a;
    }

    public boolean isB() { return !isA; }
    public B getB() {
       if(isA) throw new IllegalStateException("Not b!");
       return b;
    }

    // Purely for demo purposes...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Choice<Integer,String> ich = Choice.ofA(42);
        Choice<Integer,String> sch = Choice.ofB("foo");
        // This is why the isA is included; so we can tell a null A from a null B.
        Choice<Integer,String> nil = Choice.ofA(null);
        //
        List<Choice<Boolean,String>> xs = new ArrayList<Choice<Boolean,String>>();
        xs.add(Choice.ofA(true));
        xs.add(Choice.ofB("neep"));
    }

}
```

This should work for two unrelated classes.  Or for two *out of many* related subclasses, where you want to restrict to only those two possibilities - and not any subclass of a more general class/interface.

Such a class should probably be extended to properly implement equals()/hashCode(), toString(), etc.  (For some definition [documented] of 'properly'.)

Caveat: this may not compile first try - I don't have a javac handy to test it.  But the idea should be clear.

Comment: BTW.  The idea comes from the Scala class Either: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Either